# In salesforce order of execution diagram it is mentioned 'is this a recursive save?' what does it mean?

Tags: apex, trigger

In the salesforce order of execution diagram it is mentioned '**is this a recursive save?**' what does it mean?
If possible please provide an example
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In programming, "recursion" is when a thing calls itself.

e.g.

```
public Integer fibonacci(Integer arg1) {
    // The "base case(s)", which is what controls when the recursion ends
    if(arg1 == 0 || arg1 == 1){
        return 1;
    }

    // The "recursive case", where we call ourselves
    return fibonacci(arg1 - 1) + fibonacci(arg1 - 2);
}
```

So if you take that concept, and apply it to triggers, that would mean *an operation which causes a trigger to run, and then something happens that causes it to run again*.

I believe that the Order of Execution (OoE) diagram from architect.salesforce.com that you've referenced here is specifically referring to when you have a workflow rule (which are deprecated) with a "field update" action or a process builder (also deprecated) with a "field update" immediate action, or an after-save, record-triggered flow with a "field update" immediate action. In those cases, the same record(s) will undergo another "save procedure". Since that causes the same record to go through the trigger *again*, it is recursive.

There are other types of recursion that aren't covered by Salesforce's narrow definition in that diagram, such as:

- Inserting a new record of a given SObject inside of a (before or after) Insert trigger
- Updating a record contained within `trigger.new` or `trigger.newMap` inside of an Update trigger (while Salesforce does generally prevent this, there are ways around it)
- Indirect recursion/looping, like when you have an Insert trigger that updates a record, and an Update trigger that inserts a record

I believe the "recursive save" part of the diagram, which skips certain parts of the OoE, only applies to *updates* that happen because of workflow/process builder/flow. The other cases that I mentioned should still go through the entire OoE, and you'll run into an exception if you get more than 16 levels deep into the recursion (if you don't run into a governor limit first).

Getting 16 levels deep into trigger recursion generally means that you've missed a base case, and Salesforce has prevented you from running an infinite loop.